# What is the total supply of Monero and when will it be finished mining?

Tags: mining, emission-curve

Is there an end date of when the last monero will be mined? And what is the current supply as of today 2017 May?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Wiki it says around 18.4 Million at the end of May 2022. However,  tail emission will kick in after that which is 0.6 XMR, so it has no fixed limit.

> Its main emission curve will issue about 18.4 million coins to be mined in approximately 8 years.  (more precisely 18.132 Million coins by ca. end of May 2022[) After that, a constant "tail emission" of 0.6 XMR per 2-minutes block (modified from initially equivalent 0.3 XMR per 1-minute block) will create a sub-1% perpetual inflatio starting with 0.87% yearly inflation around May 2022) to prevent the lack of incentives for miners once a currency is not mineable anymore

From https://moneroblocks.info/, current emisssion is

```
14,445,846
```